# Friendly URL redirection not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've trying to use url redirection for 3 things:

1. Redirect to HTTPS
2. Redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com
3. Redirect from friendly url to real url without changing the url in the browser

The problem is that redirecting from friendly url, changes the url to the real one. I'd like to avoid it. Any suggestion?

Here's the piece of code in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^inconclusos.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteBase / 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
   RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ https://www.example.com/index.php?s=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks,
Pau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

# FORCE DOMAIN #
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]

# FORCE HTTPS #
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

# FRIENDLY URL #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. Domain should be the real domain and tld the .com, isn't it?

Comment: @Pau You would be correct. It's example text. Let me know if this resolved your issue.

Comment: The friendly url isn't working. Index.php can't get the param s

Comment: I realized I need to get the param with PHP and then use in JS, can't get it directly from javascript. Thanks. It was really helpful.

Comment: Yes. The browser cannot access HTTP Vars passed via .htaccess.